# I am using Peewee and I need to create migration file for my database

Tags: python, python-2.7, database-migration, psql, peewee

How should I start here, I am a bit confused.

I have database schemas which are newer than the old database.

I have seen Arnold package, where there are two methods `arnold up` and `arnold down`. There are migration files where you can add all your database queries. But still those changes I can see and I can add in `up` like `create table` or `alter table` and in `arnold down` I can add `drop table` or `alter table`. But my migration will become only for that database.

I want to understand what does database migration should contain. And what does it do. I will be very grateful if someone explain me `database migration` and push me in the right direction of peewee, psql database migration

Answer (score 3):

We use a tool [peewee-db-evolve](https://github.com/keredson/peewee-db-evolve) that I think you'll find useful.  Try this:

1. `sudo pip install peewee-db-evolve`
2. Add `import peeweedbevolve` to the top of your `models.py` file, or anywhere that is imported before the models are defined.
3. Open up your shell and run `db.evolve()` on your peewee database object.

For (3), at work we have a script `evolve.py` that looks like this:

```
import peeweedbevolve
from config import db
if __name__=='__main__': db.evolve()
```

Just to make it easy.

It will look at the models and your existing schema and calculate all the `ALTER TABLE` statements for you.  (No need to manually write the migrations as w/ arnold, or peewee's built in version.)

It'll look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: the build of peewee-db-evolve is failing , is it still being used by community or what